# Tinyproxy full of "opensock: Could not establish a connection to 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255"

Tags: proxy

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using a forward proxy to filter out bad requests on my server using Tinyproxy 1.8.4 and getting loads of these filling up the logs (in between legit activity).

Does anyone know what this is and whether I can stop it?

```
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:26 [24726]: Connect (file descriptor 7): localhost [::1]
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:26 [24726]: Request (file descriptor 7): OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:26 [24726]: opensock: Could not establish a connection to 255.255.255.255
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:26 [24726]: Error reading readable client_fd 7
WARNING   Jan 11 17:59:26 [24726]: Could not retrieve request entity
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:27 [24726]: Connect (file descriptor 7): localhost [::1]
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:27 [24726]: Request (file descriptor 7): OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:27 [24726]: opensock: Could not establish a connection to 0.0.0.0
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:27 [24726]: Error reading readable client_fd 7
WARNING   Jan 11 17:59:27 [24726]: Could not retrieve request entity
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:28 [20108]: Connect (file descriptor 7): localhost [::1]
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:28 [20108]: Request (file descriptor 7): OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:28 [20108]: opensock: Could not establish a connection to 0.0.0.0
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: Error reading readable client_fd 7
WARNING   Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: Could not retrieve request entity
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: Connect (file descriptor 7): localhost [::1]
CONNECT   Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: Request (file descriptor 7): OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: opensock: Could not establish a connection to 255.255.255.255
ERROR     Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: Error reading readable client_fd 7
WARNING   Jan 11 17:59:29 [20108]: Could not retrieve request entity
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Contact the developer.

Comment: They say it may be some app on the machine making calls and that I need to track that down. No idea how to do that though.

Comment: It should still be passing such requests to the remote site.

Comment: But I guess it can't forward requests to 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255 since there's nowhere to go?

Comment: It should never be trying in the first place.

Comment: At the moment, I have the tinyproxy config values for Listen, Bind and BindSame as the default. Perhaps I need to set those explicitly? I have two WAN IPs on the machine and want to proxy both so perhaps I can't?